# Unity Tizen target not found

Tags: unity-game-engine, tizen, tizen-certificate

Hi I try to build the Unity game for the Tizen device.
During the `Build and Run` I get following error.

[image]

Any ideas what is the `serial number 'install'`?
Can it be wrong  `DUID` in the certificate?

Comment: Did you create certificate?  And which IDE are you using ? Tizen Studio or Tizen IDE ?

Comment: Yes I created certificate for the device, without it there was error. I am using Unity Studio to deploy a game.

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the Unity Editor, go to File > **Build settings**….
- Switch to the **Tizen** platform.
- Ensure that **Development build** is checked.
- Next click on **Player Settings**.
- Under Publishing Setting enter the name of the **signing profile** that you created in the Tizen IDE. If you didn’t give it a custom name or rename it in the IDE, then you should enter “default”.
- Click the Build and Run button. Unity makes the game for you and deploys it to the device. The game then starts up on the device.
  [image]

**On Publishing Settings:**

- Make sure that on deployment target your device id is shown as per image. You have to click on **Discover** button to confirm it.
- And check your **Signing Profile Name** on Tize IDE and compare it with this setting, If doesn't match changed it in **Unity Player Settings**.

[image]

**On Other Settings:**

- Make sure your **Build Identifier** is matched with your **package name**.
- If all the things are okay, then click on **Build and Run**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was missing the `Discover` step.